# Render multiple spaces in var

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, space

I am trying to add multiple spaces in my var but it get's cut down to one space or it renders out & nbsp; as is. I have tried using & nbsp; and %20 any one have any other ideas?

> ViewBag.Subheading = "Bringing to light";

I want it to look like this

Bringing to     light

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
ViewBag.Subheading = "Bringing to light".Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
```

And

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Subheading)
```

Or you could do something like:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DisplayAndRetainSpaces(this HtmlHelper html, string value)
{
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(value.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;"));
}
```

Then call it like:

```
@Html.DisplayAndRetainSpaces(ViewBag.Subheading)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the entity for that: `&nbsp;` for each space you want.

EDIT: If you already tried and didn't work, there's an helper for outputing html, which should work with the entity:

```
 @MvcHtmlString.Create("&nbsp;");
```