# How to Add multiple space in C# string format function Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, string-formatting

I want to add more space in between

```
 @String.Format("AED       {0:0,0}", item.Price)
```

I get `AED 2,999` (Only Single Space)

I want `AED    2,999`

Found the answer with your help, Thanks Guys

```
 <div style="float: right; font-weight: initial; color: Red; float: right; margin-right: 5px">
    Price -&nbsp;&nbsp;<div style="white-space: pre;float:right;">@String.Format("AED    {0:0,0}", item.Price)</div>
 </div><br />
```

Comment: You need to wrap it in an element with `white-space: pre;` (e.g.`<div style="white-space: pre">@String.Format("AED       {0:0,0}", item.Price)</div>`)

Comment: It depends where you're doing that but take a look to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286266/render-multiple-spaces-in-var and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492249/render-a-string-in-html-and-preserve-spaces-and-newlines

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am using float right, but the text split up and price is showed in next line

Comment: In Razor View You just need to Use PRE Tag.     `<pre>@String.Format("AED       {0:0,0}", 2999)</pre>`

Comment: Why `float:right;`? And what are you trying to do with this? It looks like `AED` is the name of a property and `Price` is its value in which case you should not be trying to format like that - use 2 separate elements.

Comment: @RJK when I use pre tag, i am loosing the style

Answer (score 1):

Insert unicode whitespace \x0020 or insert tab \t?
Or "pre" tag.

`<pre>` Tag should be working:

```
<pre>@String.Format("AED       {0:0,0}", 2999)</pre>
```

[image]

Comment: @String.Format("AED \t{0:0,0}", item.OfferPrice) did not work

Comment: @String.Format("AED \x0020\x0020{0:0,0}", item.OfferPrice) did not work

Comment: It worked but i lost the styles, only color was there

Comment: you gotta be adding more css code to make pre tag more stylish :)

Answer (score 1):

It is already known that multiple spaces on formatted string will interpreted as single whitespace. To use multiple spaces (aka string alignment), use this way:

```
<pre>@String.Format("{0,-6} {1:0,0}", "AED", item.Price)</pre>
```

"-6" is an addition from length of indentation (length = 3) with "AED" string (length = 3) and a whitespace as your question stated above, with minus sign indicates left-aligned formatting. Change "-6" with other required length as you wish.

Edit: Preformatted text may retain formatted string with multiple whitespaces.

Edit 2: If you need to retain formatting (i.e. font style, color, etc), use either `<p>` or `<span>` tag, then add a CSS class like this way:

HTML

```
<span class="price">@String.Format("{0,-6} {1:0,0}", "AED", item.Price)</span>
```

CSS

```
.price {
    white-space:pre; /* or pre-wrap to enable wrapping */
}
```

Reference:

(1) http://www.csharp-examples.net/align-string-with-spaces/

(2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/433509 (reason how multiple spaces should use preformatted tag)

(3) https://stackoverflow.com/a/4503044 (CSS style to set preformatted whitespace)

Comment: And as soon as its rendered in the browser it will be collapsed again :)

Comment: Use <pre> tag around the output is possible to retain returned string.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto a little adjustment to the pre tag functionality made my day